# Download data from web using R gives libcurl error

Tags: r, web, download

I have the following R script for downloading data but it gives me an error. How can I fix this error?

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))

library('purrr')

years <- c(1980:1981)
days <- c(001:002)

walk(years, function(x) {
map(x, ~sprintf("https://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/NLDAS/NLDAS_MOS0125_H.002/%s/%s/.grb", years, days)) %>% 
  flatten_chr() -> urls
download.file(urls, basename(urls), method="libcurl")
})
```

Error:

> Error in download.file(urls, basename(urls), method = "libcurl") : 
>     download.file(method = "libcurl") is not supported on this platform 
>   I have the following R script for downloading data but it gives me an error. How can I fix this error?

Session info:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That means that `libcurl` may not be installed or available for your operative system. Please note that the `method` argument has other options and that method varies across operative systems (more or less the same as platform in the error message). I would try with other methods (e.g., `wget`, `curl`...).

From the help of `download.files`...

```
 The supported ‘method’s do change: method ‘libcurl’ was introduced
     in R 3.2.0 and is still optional on Windows - use
     ‘capabilities("libcurl")’ in a program to see if it is available.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had started to do a light edit to @gballench's answer (since I don't rly need the pts) but it's more complex than you have it since you're not going to get to the files you need with that idiom (which I'm 99% sure is from an answer of mine :-) for a whole host of reasons.

First `days` needs to be padded to length 3 with `0`s but the way you did it won't do that. Second, You likely want to download all the `.grb` files from each year/00x combo, so you need a way to get those. Finally, that site requires authentication, so you need to register and use basic authentication for it.

Something like this:

```
library(purrr)
library(httr)
library(rvest)

years <- c(1980:1981)
days <- sprintf("%03d", 1:2)

sprintf("http://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/NLDAS/NLDAS_MOS0125_H.002/%s/%%s/", years) %>% 
  map(~sprintf(.x, days)) %>% 
  flatten_chr() %>%
  map(~{
    base_url <- .x
    sprintf("%s/%s", base_url, read_html(.x) %>% 
              html_nodes(xpath=".//a[contains(@href, '.grb')]") %>% 
              html_attr("href"))
  }) %>% 
  flatten_chr() %>% 
  discard(~grepl("xml$", .)) %>% 
  walk(~{
    output_path <- file.path("FULL DIRECTORY PATH", basename(.x))
    if (!file.exists(output_path)) {
      message(.x)
      GET(
        url = .x, 
        config = httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE),
        write_disk(output_path, overwrite=TRUE),
        authenticate(user = "me@example.com", password = "xldjkdjfid8y83"),
        progress()
      )
    }
  })
```

You'll need to install the `httr` package which will install the `curl` package and ultimately make `libcurl` available for simpler batch downloads in the future.

I remembered that I had an account so I linked it with this app & tested this (killed it at 30 downloads) and it works. I added `progress()` to the `GET()` call so you can see it downloading individual files. It skips over already downloaded files (so you can kill it and restart it at any time). If you need to re-download any, just remove the file you want to re-download.

If you also need the `.xml` files, then remove the `discard()` call.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I tried your code but it gives me the following error:  Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : SSL connect error. I have an active account with this site and I used my credentials. Cannot understand what is this error about. Also, in your script is there a way to specify the output path to where the data should download?

Comment: Please see the above image for the session info.

Comment: I don't have the admin priviledge to update certificates in Ubuntu. Do you think this code will work in Windows.? Also, if it works is there  a way to specify the output data path? Just curious which OS you used to run the script. I assume this works for you.

Comment: It'll work on every OS and it turns out that you don't need HTTPS (the credentials go in the clear, unfortunately). I also added — look for  `file.path()` — a way to specify a directory for output.

Comment: Thanks gain. I tried in Windows 7 OS and its giving me a similar Error in open.connection(x,"rb"): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates

Comment: Did you try it with the change from https to http? the `sprintf("http:` line has changed. I added another line to deal with that error either way tho. I feel it's incredibly important to note that you really need to ask your administrator to upgrade that system. It's incredibly out of date and riddled with vulnerabilities (I'm in cybersecurity). These workarounds indicate that you're really at significant risk --- at the very least confidentiality/privacy risk --- in other areas on that machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I tried in Windows with your updates. http and other line of updates in your above code. Still giving me the same error. I will run in my home computer as well. As long as you tested it and working thats fine and I will find the work around for that. I will ask to upgrade my security certificates and I have something running in my computer right now after that I will restart it and see. But, anyway, thanks for the help and making me aware about the security aspect of it. I will let my admin know but everything is their hands. I will keep you posted either way.

Comment: You likely have to restart R to try that updated code which turns off peer verification. httr uses curl and curl uses libcurl and the way it works under the covers is that it caches "handles" when connections are made and those won't get updated with new "config" parameters w/o a completely new R session.